# Printing a 2D-array into "squares"

Tags: c#, arrays, random, console

I'm trying to learn how to work with 2D-array and I can't seem to understand how to print them correctly. I want to print them in a "square" like 5x5 but all I get is one line. I've tried both `WriteLine` and `Write` and changed some of the variables in the loops but I get either an error or not the result I want to have. The code is supposed to print out a 5x5 with a random sequence of 15 numbers in each column. I get the correct numbers out of it, it's only the layout that is wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[,] bricka = new int[5, 5];
    int num = 0;
    int num1 = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < bricka.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        num += 16;
        for (int j = 0; j < bricka.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            bricka[j, i] = rnd.Next(num1, num);
        }
        num1 += 16;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bricka.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bricka.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(bricka[i, j]+ " " );
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is my print, I would like to have the the 12 under the 8 and 14 under the 12 and so on.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/19MrT.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `WriteLine()` after each line, so that each line is printed on a separate line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bricka.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bricka.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(bricka[i, j]+ " " );
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

That would be one way of doing it, anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what the "sqaure" is called in c#, i guess it's not called squares due to the irrelevant google searches.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand that question. C# doesn't have a "squares" data type per se. So you can call your data structure representing a square whatever you like. Even "square". :)

Comment: Oh, i see. But in my first code i got the result as in one line vertically or horizontally depending write/writeline. With your code i got the result as in a "square" in lack of better words.5x5, 5 rows and 5 column. Do you understand? :)

Comment: I suppose another name for that particular visual layout would be "grid". That's the term used in graphic APIs like Winforms, WPF, XAML, etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @halalbin I think you can call it a two dimensional matrix